# htacces remove folder from custom url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following code on my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cp/artes-escenicas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/ciencia-y-tecnologia/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/arte-y-diseno/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/deportes/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/idiomas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/academico/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/rutas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cp/voluntariado/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

this allow me to have the following URL's:

```
http://pepperscope.com/cp/index.php
http://pepperscope.com/cp/artes-escenicas
http://pepperscope.com/cp/ciencia-y-tecnologia
http://pepperscope.com/cp/arte-y-diseno
http://pepperscope.com/cp/arte-y-diseno
http://pepperscope.com/cp/deportes
http://pepperscope.com/cp/campamentos
http://pepperscope.com/cp/idiomas
http://pepperscope.com/cp/academico
http://pepperscope.com/cp/rutas
http://pepperscope.com/cp/voluntariado
http://pepperscope.com/cp/lifestyle
```

But I need two things:

1) have the root on pepperscope.com instead of pepperscope.com/cp/index.php

2) remove the cp folder from all my links, like that:

```
http://pepperscope.com/artes-escenicas
http://pepperscope.com/ciencia-y-tecnologia
http://pepperscope.com/arte-y-diseno
http://pepperscope.com/arte-y-diseno
http://pepperscope.com/deportes
http://pepperscope.com/campamentos
http://pepperscope.com/idiomas
http://pepperscope.com/academico
http://pepperscope.com/rutas
http://pepperscope.com/voluntariado
http://pepperscope.com/lifestyle
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the cp after `^`, so something like this.

Remove all cp folders from all links

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^artes-escenicas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ciencia-y-tecnologia/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^arte-y-diseno/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^deportes/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^idiomas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^academico/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^rutas/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^voluntariado/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

To fix the problem with the root, best thing I can come up with is this

```
RewriteRule ^([/]?)$  cp/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks that help form the categories, but I still have the problem with the root, also, I have links like <a href="artes-escenicas">artes escenicas</a> but his links still point to cp/artes-escenicas, any idea what else I have to do????

Comment: In your HTML `<head> .. </head>` do you have any tags called `<base>` ?

Comment: yes, but if I remove it a lost all css and js files

Comment: solve it, but I still need the www.pepperscope.com as a root insted of www.pepperscope.com/cp/index.php, any idea???

Comment: Yeah, give me a few mins I need to try it out before I post the answer.